# No route matches {:action=>"vote_up", :controller=>"posts"} error for thumbs_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, voting, voting-system

I'm trying to implement the thumbs_up gem into my app and I keep getting this error even though I have a route for the vote_up action

My posts controller looks like

```
   def vote_up
     begin
       current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))
       render :nothing => true, :status => 200
     rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
       render :nothing => true, :status => 404
     end
   end
```

My route looks like

```
   resources :posts do
     get :vote_up, :on => :member
     resources :comments
   end
```

I don't know what the problem is, if anyone could help me or point me to a tutorial to use the thumbs_up gem that would be great.

Comment: can you share your view code?

Comment: `current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))`. IMHO an assignment used also as an argument to a method is not good programming practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're requesting `vote_up` without an id for a post. Just looking at your controller:

`current_user.vote_for(@post = Post.find(params[:id]))`

Yet I do not see any `id` field in your request. The problem lies in your view.

Comment: Agreed. The `vote_up` route is on a member resource. The error is because you're not passing the `id` parameter along to this route.

Comment: @Jordan Scales: What should the corrected code look like? How do you put the id into the request?